# How to allow community users to modify their contacts without seeing other contacts

Tags: apex, community, security, permissions

We have a customer community using custom apex controllers that look up and modify the community user's associated contact (based off `User.ContactId`). I'd like to set the permissions for the community user profile so that they are able to edit their own contacts, but can't see or edit other user's contacts.

How can this be done? Is it possible to assign the customer community users as owners of their own contact record (the customer users don't seem to appear as a choice in the owner field lookup)?